# Python encoding declaration appears to be getting ignored?

Tags: python, character-encoding

The following code is saved as a utf-8 encoded text file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print 'é'
```

When I run the above code on the command line in Linux using Python 2.7, I get the output `é` as expected.

If I change the encoding declaration in the file from utf-8 to cp1252 and re-run it I get the same output `é`.

But shouldn't Python now be interpreting the `é` in the file, stored as hex `c3a9`, as cp1252 encoded text? In which case the output should be `Ã©`?

If I force my text editor to view the file as cp1252 encoded text the `é` changes to `Ã©`. Why isn't Python doing the same?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Changing the coding directive does change the output of the program for me. However, you are ignoring one unknown in your setup, which is how the output of the program is interpreted and rendered. Maybe this helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we declare `# -*- coding: ... -*-` (or just `# coding: ...`), we're telling Python the source file is saved in the declared encoding.
So, encoding declaration matters, but until the source file is valid in the declared encoding and we don't use `u`-literals, changing the declared encoding will not affect the printout.

To check the last statement let`s have a look at:

---

#### Effects of the encoding declaration.

**1. SyntaxError test.**

First of all Python uses the declared encoding for the `SyntaxError` test.
For example, let's run the following source file which is saved in `utf-8`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print repr('Á') # '\xc3\x81'
```

As it follows from the printout: the `utf-8` bytes for the `Á` character are: `\xc3\x81`.
Let's change the declared encoding and run the file again:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
print repr('Á')
```

Now it fails with the error:

```
SyntaxError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 13: character maps to <undefined>
```

The source is still in `utf-8` but now the `\xc3\x81` byte-sequence is not valid in the declared encoding (`cp1252`) because in this encoding the `\x81` byte maps to `UNDEFINED`.

---

At the same time the `utf-8` bytes for the `é` character are: `\xc3\xa9` and this byte-sequence is valid in `cp1252`. Therefore, in this case it doesn't matter which encoding is declared - `utf-8` or `cp1252` - the bytes mentioned above will pass the `SyntaxError` test:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print repr('é') # '\xc3\xa9'
```

```py
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
print repr('é') # '\xc3\xa9'
```

and afterwards they will be printed/decoded through `sys.stdout.encoding`:
(*approximately* as in the example below)

```
import sys
bytes_in = '\xc3\xa9'
enc_out = sys.stdout.encoding
chars_out = '\xc3\xa9'.decode(enc_out)
print chars_out # 'é' if enc_out == 'utf-8'
```

`sys.stdout.encoding` depends on the environment and doesn't on the declared encoding.
That's why you get the same output when the source file is in the same encoding.

---

**2. Interpretation of Unicode literals**

However, the encoding declaration affects on how Python interprets unicode-strings which are declared with `u`-literals:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print repr(u'é') # u'\xe9'
```

```py
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
print repr(u'é') # u'\xc3\xa9'
```

In the last example Python interprets `u'é'` as
*unicode-string decoded from `\xc3\xa9` bytes through `cp1252` encoding*:

```
print repr(unicode('\xc3\xa9', 'cp1252')) # u'\xc3\xa9'
```

Let's print this unicode-string:

```
print unicode('\xc3\xa9', 'cp1252') # Ã©
```

Therefore, you can get the `Ã©` output using unicode-literal for `é` in the case the source file is in `utf-8` and the declared encoding is `cp1252`:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
print u'é' # Ã©
```

---

For more information you can check this:

[PEP 263 -- Defining Python Source Code Encodings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

[The source of Python's tokenizer function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f805628625e0cf4ee2d420735f7b15a93715aca/Parser/tokenizer.c)

Comment: Really detailed and informative answer. I actually typed out all the examples you gave and that really helped my understanding of the subject. Good work :)